# Cannot install library

Tags: software-installation, 20.04, libraries

I am following [this](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/motionbuilder/troubleshooting/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2019/ENU/Installation-MotionBuilder/files/GUID-4698304C-445C-41BC-933F-779E96240A76-htm.html) guide, but when running the ./setup command I get the response:

```
./setup-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I see a similar [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1137814/trouble-installing-libpng12-on-19-04), but it isn't helping. My files show that I have libpng12.so.0, but it doesn't show that it's installed, and won't let me install it.
[image: files]
Do I have the wrong files downloaded?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way I've solved this problem was by creating a symlink from the older library to the newer (in your case, from libpng12.so.0 to libpng16.so.0) No package installation necessary, although I remember that it may get broken again if libpng16 is updated, for example to libpng12.so.1